# Count number occurrences of element / value occurs in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count, slice

How do I count the number of times an element/ value occurs in a list of lists?

I want to return the number of times **test** occurs.

```
my_list = [['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah']]
print(my_list.count('test'))
>>> 0
```

Desired output: 5

Secondly, I want to only check/ count **test** the first element of each list, e.g. `my_list[0/1/2/...][0]`

Comment: I can't yet is why. Saves people from wasting time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
print(sum(x.count('test') for x in my_list))
# 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain all sublists then count

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah']]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(my_list)).count('test')
5
```

Answer (score 1):

The below-given solution can help you to count the number of occurrences in a given list:

```
my_list = [['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah'], ['test', 'idk', 'blah']]

n_ocurrences = sum([sublist.count("test") for sublist in my_list])
```

Using a list comprehension, we can loop the sub-list inside a list, `my_list`, and the `list.count` method will help us to count the occurrences.